# Как правильно сделать сортировку в Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Есть продукция

```
name               | price | company_id

товар 1 компании 1 | 10    | 1
товар 2 компании 1 | 10    | 1
товар 3 компании 1 | 20    | 1
товар 4 компании 2 | 10    | 2
товар 5 компании 2 | 10    | 2
товар 6 компании 2 | 20    | 2
товар 7 компании 3 | 10    | 3
товар 8 компании 3 | 10    | 3
товар 9 компании 3 | 20    | 3
```

Требуется отсортировать по цене и по id компании, но что бы компании чередовались

И получили такой результат

```
name               | price | company_id

товар 1 компании 1 | 10    | 1
товар 4 компании 2 | 10    | 2
товар 7 компании 3 | 10    | 3
товар 2 компании 1 | 10    | 1
товар 5 компании 2 | 10    | 2
товар 8 компании 3 | 10    | 3
товар 3 компании 1 | 20    | 1
товар 6 компании 2 | 20    | 2
товар 9 компании 3 | 20    | 3
```

Не знаю как правильно загуглить, где можно прочитать про подобную сортировку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примеру это обычная сортировка по нескольким полям, когда вы сортируете по более чем одному полю, основная сортировка происходит по первому указанному полю, в вашем случае это цена, второе поле это id компании по которому сортировка будет производится только когда у документов в индексе одинаковое значение первого поля.
Вообще о сортировке в Elasticsearch можно почитать в документации -
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html